# Transferring string values across Subroutines

Tags: vb.net, byref, byval

I have the variables Month1 & Month2 which I need to somehow transfer across to frmMain_Load from cb_CheckedChanged. If there isn't any way of transferring the String values could I possibly change some of the code to make it possible?

```
Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub cb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chckJan.
   CheckedChanged,
   chckFeb.CheckedChanged,
   chckMar.CheckedChanged,
   chckApr.CheckedChanged,
   chckMay.CheckedChanged,
    chckJun.CheckedChanged,
   chckJul.CheckedChanged,
    chckAug.CheckedChanged,
chckOct.CheckedChanged,
  chckNov.CheckedChanged,
   chckDec.CheckedChanged


    'get all checkboxes
    Dim Months = Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().ToArray()
    'Get the number of checked CheckBoxes.
    Dim checkedBoxCount = Months.Count(Function(cb) cb.Checked)
    'Unchecked CheckBoxes should be enabled if and only if the number of checked CheckBoxes is less than the maximum number allowed.
    Dim enableUncheckedBoxes = checkedBoxCount < 2
    'Get the unchecked CheckBoxes.
    Dim uncheckedBoxes = Months.Where(Function(cb) Not cb.Checked)
    'Enable or disable the unchecked CheckBoxes as appropriate.
    For Each uncheckedBox In uncheckedBoxes
        uncheckedBox.Enabled = enableUncheckedBoxes
    Next

    Dim Month1 As String
    Dim Month2 As String

    Dim CheckBoxArray1 As CheckBox() = {chckJan, chckFeb, chckMar, chckApr, chckMay, chckJun, chckJul, chckAug, chckSep, chckOct, chckNov, chckDec}
    For Each CheckBox In CheckBoxArray1
        If CheckBox.Checked = True And checkedBoxCount = 1 Then
            Month1 = CheckBox.Name.ToString
        End If
    Next

    Dim CheckBoxArray2 As CheckBox() = {chckJan, chckFeb, chckMar, chckApr, chckMay, chckJun, chckJul, chckAug, chckSep, chckOct, chckNov, chckDec}
    For Each CheckBox In CheckBoxArray2
        If CheckBox.Checked = True And checkedBoxCount = 2 Then
            Month2 = CheckBox.Name.ToString
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Comment: You can't, events declarations cannot be changed. frmMain_Load is a routine which runs on the event of `Load`, note `Handles MyBase.Load`

Comment: FormLoad runs once and only once, and before you will ever check any checkboxes

Comment: Is there a way to get round the handle??? @Jezzabeanz

Comment: Put the code you want to run into a Sub.  Call it from FormLoad, also call it at the end of your long CheckChanged event

Comment: Plutonix is correct, anything that you're doing in your Form_Load, you can do in a sub routine.

Comment: Okay. Now the bloody grids ain't filling up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not sure what your end goal is, but it seems like you need something like this:

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private Month1 As String
    Private Month2 As String

    Private Sub cb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
        chckJan.CheckedChanged, chckFeb.CheckedChanged, chckMar.CheckedChanged,
        chckApr.CheckedChanged, chckMay.CheckedChanged, chckJun.CheckedChanged,
        chckJul.CheckedChanged, chckAug.CheckedChanged, chckSep.CheckedChanged,
        chckOct.CheckedChanged, chckNov.CheckedChanged, chckDec.CheckedChanged

        Dim CheckBoxes As CheckBox() = {
            chckJan, chckFeb, chckMar, chckApr,
            chckMay, chckJun, chckJul, chckAug,
            chckSep, chckOct, chckNov, chckDec}

        Dim checkedBoxes = CheckBoxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked)
        For Each curCB In CheckBoxes.Where(Function(cb) Not cb.Checked)
            curCB.Enabled = (checkedBoxes.Count < 2)
        Next
        If checkedBoxes.Count = 2 Then
            Month1 = checkedBoxes.First.Text
            Month2 = checkedBoxes.Last.Text
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's perfect sir! Few touches and it's sorted!